# Maxima convert string to integer in a list

Tags: string, maxima

I started to work with the software Maxima and I have a pb to convert string into a integer:

[list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXjHT.png)

Because I want to manipulate these elements but maxima organize characters by alphabetic order and it's a problem for me, so I would like to convert the list with strings into a list with integers but I don't find nice command to do that.

Can you help me ?

Best regards

Comment: Can you give an example? Also in the image the strings are not in alphabetic order.

Comment: I think you'll need to explain what you mean by a list with integers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I solved my problem !